# Why the motion tracking results are jumpy after rendering it by sheep it?

Tags: tracking, sheepit

I did a very smooth camera movement and the solving error was too low and the tracking was so stable but after rendering it by sheep it render farm i received a very jumpy camera movement. Is it because of the difference between the graphics cards or processors? And after that I tried to render it only by processes and I received the same results !! Any suggestions ??

Comment: No, GPU or CPU speed should not affect tracking accuracy. Is the motion tracking data baked into an fcurve? If you are asking the farm to solve the tracking, it's likely that it's unable to deal with loading the frames out of order.

Comment: No i'm not asking the render farm to solve the tracking  and i'm not using the fcurve. what should i do in this case ? :(